# Index out of range error? Roblox Auto-login using Cookie(s)

Tags: c#, cookies, indexof, roblox

I am new to stackoverflow, How are ya'll?

Anyways, i am getting an error about Index out of range, for an auto-login program for roblox using my cookie(s), Error stats:

> **Error on line: 183:**
>
> ```
> int End = resp.Headers[item].IndexOf("\n domain=", Start);
> ```

the full error message is :

```
The index is out of range. It can not be negative and must be smaller than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: startIndex'
```

my code:

```
private string RBLXAutoLogin(string user, string pass)
{
    try
    {
        string json = $"{{\"password\":\"{ pass }\", \"username\":\"{ user }\"}}";
        HttpWebRequest loginReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.roblox.com/newlogin");
        loginReq.Method = "POST";
        loginReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        loginReq.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json).Length;

        using (var sr = new StreamWriter(loginReq.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            sr.Write(json);
            sr.Flush();
            sr.Close();
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)loginReq.GetResponse())
        {
            foreach (string item in resp.Headers.Keys)
            {
                if (item == "Set-Cookie")
                {
                    int Start = resp.Headers[item].IndexOf(".ROBLOSECURITY=_", 0);   
                    Console.WriteLine(resp.Headers[item].IndexOf(".ROBLOSECURITY=_", 0));
                    int End = resp.Headers[item].IndexOf("\n domain=", Start);
                    Console.WriteLine(resp.Headers[item].Substring(Start, End - Start).Replace(".ROBLOSECURITY=", ""));
                    return resp.Headers[item].Substring(Start, End - Start).Replace(".ROBLOSECURITY=", "");
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch(WebException wex)
    {
        return wex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi!  Can you post the complete error message, and on which line does it come?

Comment: Ofcourse, let me edit!

Comment: Your Start value is negative; IndexOf doesn't find searched string.

Answer (score 0):

You want this?

```
if (item == "Set-Cookie")
{
    int Start = resp.Headers[item].IndexOf(".ROBLOSECURITY=_", 0);   
    if (Start >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(resp.Headers[item].IndexOf(".ROBLOSECURITY=_", 0));
        int End = resp.Headers[item].IndexOf("\n domain=", Start);
        Console.WriteLine(resp.Headers[item].Substring(Start, End - Start).Replace(".ROBLOSECURITY=", ""));
        return resp.Headers[item].Substring(Start, End - Start).Replace(".ROBLOSECURITY=", "");
    }
}
```